# Prove: $\frac{\frac{1}{a}+b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+a}}+\frac{\frac{1}{b}+c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}+b}}+\frac{\frac{1}{c}+a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}+c}}\ge3\sqrt{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that: $$\frac{\frac{1}{a}+b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+a}}+\frac{\frac{1}{b}+c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}+b}}+\frac{\frac{1}{c}+a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}+c}}\ge3\sqrt{2}$$

Anyone help me a hint to solve above problem?
I tried by AM-GM without success: $$LHS\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(\frac{1}{a}+b\right)\left(\frac{1}{b}+c\right)\left(\frac{1}{c}+a\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{a}+a\right)\left(\frac{1}{b}+b\right)\left(\frac{1}{c}+c\right)}}}$$
The rest is proving: $$\left(\frac{1}{a}+b\right)\left(\frac{1}{b}+c\right)\left(\frac{1}{c}+a\right)\ge2\sqrt{2\left(\frac{1}{a}+a\right)\left(\frac{1}{b}+b\right)\left(\frac{1}{c}+c\right)}$$ which is not true by a=60,b=0.02 and c=0.9

Thank you for your help!

Comment: AM-GM usually works on homogeneous inequalities unless you get some restriction like $a+b+c = 1, abc = 2$ etc. So I wouldn't go for it.

Comment: You meant it is incorrect ?

Comment: It's not incorrect, it's just too weak.

Comment: Can you share your solution? I don't think it is weak

Comment: Why did you say it too weak?

Comment: Anyone help me?

Comment: @Mars Will try, but cannot be too sure. The meaning of any inequality being  "too weak"  is that ,as an estimate, it is not good enough to solve the problem. You need an inequality that actually leaves very little gap between the LHS and RHS. AM-GM often does a job, but in this case, it looks like something better is required. What, remains to be seen. I will read a few similar problems and get back to you.

Comment: I see generalization on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h2741650p23915502

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma:** [From this problem that the OP posed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338382/a-b0-then-frac1a2b2-ge-sqrt2-frac1a2a2b-a1?noredirect=1&lq=1) (with terms rearranged),for $ a_i > 0$,

$$ \frac{ \frac{1}{ a_i } + a_{i+1} } { \sqrt{ \frac{1}{ a_i } + a_{i} } } \geq \sqrt{2} ( \sqrt{a_{i+1}} - \sqrt{a_i} + 1 ). $$

**Corollary:** This inequality follows by summing up over $a_i$, and the RHS simplifies to $ 3 \sqrt{2} $.

---

Notes

- Furthermore, we get the obvious generalization to $n$ variables, $ \sum \frac{ \frac{1}{ a_i } + a_{i+1} } { \sqrt{ \frac{1}{ a_i } + a_{i} } } \geq n \sqrt{2}$.
- Guessing this lemma isn't obvious to me. Proving it also requires some manipulation.

Comment: Two more proofs [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/vmo.tst/posts/885374268843371)

Comment: Did you know the author? He is my master of mine

Answer (score 1):

Using [Radon's inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/RadonInequality.shtml) we need to show :

$$\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}+b\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(\frac{1}{b}+c\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(\frac{1}{c}+a\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{a+b+c+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}}-3\sqrt{2}\geq 0$$

Can you end now ?

Follow up

Let $x_i>0$, $1\leq i\leq 3=n$, such that $x_1=x_{4}$ then we have :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{1}{x_i}+x_{i+1}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_i}+x_i}}\geq 3\sqrt{2}\tag{I}$$

At first glance it seems that Am-Gm is too weak so as above I use Radon's inequality (see vivid edit) we need to show :

$$\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}+x_{i+1}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}+x_i\right)}}\geq 3\sqrt{2}$$

Then I used Minkowski's inequality with $p=\frac{2}{3}$ we need to show :

$$\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}+x_i\right)}}\geq 3\sqrt{2}$$

Edit :

We can apply Jensen's inequality and we need to show  :

$$\frac{2^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_{i}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_{i}}+x_{i}\right)}}-3\sqrt{2}\geq 0$$

Idea to conclude for the case $n=3$:

the function $x>0$ and $a,b\geq 4$:

$$f(x)=\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}+a\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+b\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot6$$

We have :

$$f(x)\geq f(1)$$

Using this lemma a judicious number of times the conclusion follow for the case $n=3$.

Comment: How about other cases dear sir?

Comment: @Mars I think I got something !

Comment: Very beautiful! Thanks

Comment: @Mars Now it's complete thanks for the nice problem !!